# Creating two finite sets using a class

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have defined a class for a finite set as follows:

```
class FiniteSet a where
elements :: [a]
```

Now, I want to create two Char set, let's say A = {'a','c','f'} and B = {'x','y'}. How would I do that? However, I tried to create a Char instance as follows, but what after that?

```
instance FiniteSet Char where
elements = []
```

Thanks.

Comment: These are two completely different questions. I strongly recommend you pick one to keep here; make an edit to delete the other one and open a fresh question with it instead.

Comment: You probably want to define a type rather than a class. Classes in Haskell are not types.

Comment: If you're coming from Java, a typeclass in Haskell is more akin to an interface in Java. Haskell typeclasses are NOT OO classes.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want to say

```
type FiniteSet a = [a]
a = ['a', 'c', 'f'] -- = "acf"
b = ['x', 'y']      -- = "xy"
```

or possibly

```
newtype FiniteSet a = FiniteSet { elements :: [a] }
a = FiniteSet ['a', 'c', 'f']
b = FiniteSet ['x', 'y']
```

if you want to make sure you don't mix up `FiniteSet`s and lists.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll try to give you some hints on my opinion on this.

The first question you should ask yourself is **Do I need a `class`**? (I don't think so here but let's go with it).

---

The way you choose to do it tells us this:

When a type `a` is an instance of `FinitSet` then we can get **one** list of elements `[a]` back and that is one for the *type* not a value of the type - which I doubt is what you want.

Maybe you thought to have something like this:

```
class FiniteSet a where
    elements :: a -> [a]
```

Here you could get some list for a given value but still this looks strange doesn't it? Given a value you get yet more of the same? So maybe you the type of the elements you get should be different from the instance-type?

```
class FiniteSet i e where
    elements :: i -> [e]
```

but now you will certainly run into situations where you wonder why `i` does not imply `e` and you will search and look and find *Functional Dependencies* and stuff and it will more complicated by the second.

So I think you don't really want it that way.

---

Maybe instead you want to capture the essence of what it is to be a set - something like:

```
class FiniteSet i e where
    count   :: i -> Int
    empty   :: i
    isElem  :: i -> e -> Bool
    addElem :: i -> e -> i
```

this way you could end up with something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

module FinSet where

class FiniteSet i e | i -> e where
  count   :: i -> Int
  empty   :: i
  isElem  :: e -> i -> Bool
  addElem :: i -> e -> i

instance Eq a => FiniteSet [a] a where
  count xs     = length xs
  empty        = []
  isElem x xs  = x `elem` xs
  addElem xs x = if x `elem` xs then xs else x:xs
```

see how you still need lot's of extensions just to define an instance for a simple list that just uses what you already have in a list?

---

#### remark

This is what I meant when I told you that I don't think you need/want a class as it seems that you just want a type-synonym/`newtype` for a list

---

Anyway this will give you some way to construct sets:

```
λ> let fin = (empty `addElem` 'a' `addElem` 'b' `addElem` 'c')

λ> count fin
3
λ> 'b' `isElem` fin
True
λ> 'd' `isElem` fin
False
λ> fin `addElem` 'a'
"cba"
```

---

the problem of course is that you will not get any gurantee that will even be finite (it's just lists for this instance) and to be honest I don't see a way to *rescue* us in this situation right now:

```
λ> let nats = foldr (flip addElem) empty [0..]
```

Comment: I actually need the class and there are lots of things defined on this class, after finishing the code when I was trying to make an example to run the system, the issue arrived. Anyway, I fixed it as follows, thanks a lot.

    data A = A | C | F
    instance FiniteSet Char where
        elements = [A,C,F]

Comment: @Wazed Why do you say you need the class?

Comment: Hi, this is because I have a long system defined on the FiniteSet class. Adopting something else now would make the situation even worse and I actually don't have much time left, that's part of my research. Thanks.